# A question about clist function and tabular (LaTeX3)

Tags: tables, expl3, latex3

This is MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expl3}

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \l_my_clist
\clist_new:N \l_my_tmp_clist
\clist_set:Nn \l_my_clist { x, y }
\begin{tabular}{cc}
  \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_my_clist
    { 
      \clist_set:Nn \l_my_tmp_clist { #1 }
      a & \clist_item:Nn \l_my_tmp_clist { 1 } \\
    }
\end{tabular}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

My question is: Why LaTeX outputs like

```
a &  \\
a &  \\
```

instead of

```
a & x \\
a & y \\
```

Comment: tabular cells are groups.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer What do I need to do to achieve the result below?

Comment: sorry but it is quite unclear what you are trying to do with the tmp clist. In your example simply `\clist_map_inline:Nn \l_my_clist {a&#1\\}`  would work.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer This is because in the class file I am writing, the parameter is still a clist. I have to get item from it. I just found an ugly solution. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @Eliauk instead of assigning in the first column and using the variable in the second you can just omit the variable and use `\clist_item:nn {#1} {1}` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\clist_map_inline:Nn` is a non-expandable function, which means it cannot be expanded inside a x-type argument. More precisely, the above-mentioned case can be seen equivalently as packing everything inside `tabular` environment into a tokenlist, in an unchanged way. When the content of this tokenlist is divided into individual cells, we can see that the commands that assign the variable and extract value are executed locally, resulting in the `\clist_item:Nn` accessing the initial empty clist.

We can do a little test to verify this.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \l_my_clist
\clist_new:N \l_my_tmp_clist
\clist_set:Nn \l_my_clist { x, y }
\exp_args:Nx \tl_show:n
  {
    \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_my_clist
      { 
        \clist_set:Nn \l_my_tmp_clist { ##1 }
        a & \clist_item:Nn \l_my_tmp_clist { 1 } \\
      }
  }
\end{document}
```

I come up two ways to settle this problem. The simpler approach is to replace `\clist_set:Nn` with its global counterpart.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \l_my_clist
\clist_new:N \l_my_tmp_clist
\clist_set:Nn \l_my_clist { x, y }
\begin{tabular}{cc}
  \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_my_clist
    { 
      \clist_gset:Nn \l_my_tmp_clist { #1 }
      a & \clist_item:Nn \l_my_tmp_clist { 1 } \\
    }
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

And the second way is to expand the variable to its actual value beforehand.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \l_my_clist
\clist_new:N \l_my_tmp_clist
\clist_set:Nn \l_my_clist { x, y }

\tl_clear:N \l_tmpa_tl
\clist_map_inline:Nn \l_my_clist
  { 
    \clist_set:Nn \l_my_tmp_clist { #1 }
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l_tmpa_tl
      { a & \clist_item:Nn \l_my_tmp_clist { 1 } \\ }
  }
% \tl_show:N \l_tmpa_tl

\begin{tabular}{cc}
  \l_tmpa_tl
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```